# Display sub query result ADODB in Smarty

Tags: php, mysql, subquery, smarty, adodb

I'm making 2 queries in my PHP file. The 2nd depends on the first and I would like to display the results in my Smarty template.

However, it doesn't display the good results. Here is the code:

First, the query:

```
$sql            = "SELECT * FROM albums order by id ASC";
$rs             = $conn->execute($sql);
$galeries       = $rs->getrows();

foreach ( $galeries as $galerie ) {
    $sqlgal = "SELECT id, filename, id_album FROM pictures where id_album = ".$galerie['id']." order by id ASC limit 0,1 ";
    echo $sqlgal;
    $rsgal = $conn->execute($sqlgal);
    $picture1 = $rsgal->getrows();
}
```

and I assigned results to variables:

```
$oSmarty->assign('galeries', $galeries);
$oSmarty->assign('pictures', $picture1);
```

Now in my template :

```
{section name=i loop=$galeries}
<div class="item">
    <div class="well">
    <a href="/galerie/{$galeries[i].id}/{$galeries[i].title|clean}.html" class="thumbnail"><img src="/photos/{$galeries[i].filename}/{$pictures[i].filename}" class="img-responsivetotal"></a>
    </div>
</div>
{/section}
```

I have the information about the galerie but the picture filename doesn't appear. What's wrong? I couldn't find anything about subqueries in ADODB.

Answer (score 0):

The logic in your php code concerning the pictures seems wrong: you loop over every gallery:

```
foreach ( $galeries as $galerie )
```

and in each of those loops you assign data to $picture1, destroying any data from the previous loop:

```
$picture1 = $rsgal->getrows();
```

so, in the end, $pictures1 only has the picture from the last gallery. I suppose you forgot to auto increment the array:

```
$picture1[] = $rsgal->getrows();
```